# numpy eig vs svd . Why they produce different resutls

Tags: python, numpy, svd, eigenvalue, eigenvector

I am trying to grok the idea and  behavior of numpy svd vs eig.
Why do they produce different results? Am I comparing apples to apples here ?
Hope my usage is correct.
Here is my simple dumb down code trying to grok the SVD and Eigen vector

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn import preprocessing

np.random.seed(123)
np.set_printoptions(suppress=True)

X = np.random.rand(2, 3)
X1 = preprocessing.scale(X, axis=1)

cov = np.matmul(X1.T, X1)/X1.shape[0]
U,S,V = np.linalg.svd(cov)
eig_vals, eig_vec = np.linalg.eig(cov)

ids = eig_vals.argsort()[::-1]
eig_vals = eig_vals[ids]
eig_vec = eig_vec[:,ids]
print("SVD: \n U_svd: \n {} \n V_svd:\n {}\n".format( U, V))
print("Eig: \n U_eig: \n {} \n V_eig: \n {}\n".format(eig_vec, eig_vals))
```

U's are pretty close. However the Eigen vals differ by a lot. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

The eigenvalues differ from the singular values because they are the square of S as noted in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition#Relation_to_eigenvalue_decomposition

This means that your singular value is the square root of the eigenvalue divided by the number of samples. One way to look at this is to go to scikit-learn's code for PCA (https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/main/sklearn/decomposition/_pca.py), and you can see what all they do; the explained variance is determined from the singular value.